# Replace Tokens from Webform Submission in DOCX

Tags: webforms, tokens

This is my first question here at Drupal Answers and I try to be as precise as possible.

I'm using Drupal 9 and the current version of the webform module.
What I am trying to do is replacing tokens (placeholders) in a DOCX file with values submitted with a webform.

To get this work I wrote a custom Webform Handler. This handler provides a file upload where I submit the DOCX that contains the placeholders, which should be replaced later. The file upload works, the handler is able to load the file during submission:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
...
}
```

However, I am not able to replace the tokens from the webform/submission in the DOCX using this code:

```
$token_service = \Drupal::token();
$token_options = ['clear' => TRUE];
$data = array(
    'webform' => $webform,
    'webform-submission' => $webform_submission,
);
$xml = $token_service->replace($xml, $data, $token_options);
```

$xml is the complete text from the DOCX.
$webform is the webform object loaded from the submission $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();

The string I got from the DOCX (extracting the zip and load the XML) contains "tokens" exactly as the tokens that are the fields in my webform.
Example: `[submission:values:angaben_zur_zukuenftigen_gesellschaft:gesellschaftssitz]`

The webform contains a fieldset with the machine name `angaben_zur_zukuenftigen_gesellschaft` as well as a field with the machine name `gesellschaftssitz`. Respecting this the formatting in the DOCX file should be correct.
Nevertheless I'm not able to replace the tokens in the DOCX with tokens from the webform submission even when `$token_service->replace($xml, $data, $token_options);` returns a string with cleaned tokens.
That means the token replace method itself works but not with the provided data - they can't be used to replace the DOCX tokens.

I appreciate any help.

Alex